# Python script that calls itself

Tags: python

I have Python script that is called with couple of arguments.
I also can call it with different set of arguments to behave differently.

my questions is : is it possible that in the script, when I call it with second set of arguments, I add code so that the script calls itself with first set of arguments? will that work?

Reason for above:
 When called with argument set 1, script builds a C library.
 When called with argument set 2, script runs the dll build from arg set 1.
 However, I found that running with argument set 2 also requires one of the C  files (that builds the dll) to have absolute paths(it has relative). Running the python script with argument 2, i temporarily change 
the C file relative to absolute paths and run, but this means script is out of sync with dll. so, I need to call script with second set of argument , have code in this, that  will call same script again with first set of arguments to build the dll and then proceed further .
Thanks
sedy

Comment: Sure, just check the arguments and do whatever you want accordingly. But why do you want to create a new process? Can't you just call another function inside the script?

Comment: Named or optional parameters can be helpful when you want to know what arguments were ( and were not) passed into a function. http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
from subprocess import call
if arg2:
    call(["python", "myscript.py", "--arg1"])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change in argumemts will have no side effects on function, its same as
>   any instruction.

It should work. Its much easier than what you are afraid of. Do it now, its fun.

> The * next to args means "take the rest of the parameters given and
>   put them in a list called args".

```
def wrapper(func, *args):
    func(*args)

def func1(x):
    print(x)

def func2(x, y, z):
    print x+y+z

wrapper(func1, 1)
wrapper(func2, 1, 2, 3)
```